# How to fix "status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied"? when I call API using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call API to POST Request I get error 403 and "has been blocked by CORS Policy.

This is my Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: $('meta[name="server-config"]').attr('content') + "/file/upload/?user_id=" + response.user_id,
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${$('meta[name=auth-key]').attr('content')}`
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        // location.reload();
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should allow cross origin from your server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 0):

In your post method file add the following header and try

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: I tried this but still same error.
` headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${$('meta[name=auth-key]').attr('content')}`
}`

Comment: Where did you exactly added it?

Comment: Yes, do not add it there. Try adding it in the file (at the top) where you redirect the mentioned URL.

Comment: I put the headers at the top of the file but still same result. please see picture https://imgur.com/a/isyPh1w

Comment: Add this in your php file (i guess it is user_management) at the top

  `<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");`

Comment: i dont know what happen but still same result